# Datatables Export to Excel not showing updated info

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

The export to Excel in Datatables is working as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#datatableABC').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtipl',
    "lengthMenu": [[100, 250, -1], [100, 250, "All"]],
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'print']     
  });
});
```

However if I update the table contents via jquery using `$("#field2").text("text here");` then the info is shown in the datatable, but when I press the Excel button it exports the data that was in the column originally ?

Answer (score 2):

By doing `$("#field2").text("text here");` you are only updating the text inside td element in html. Datatables library maintains an object to store your table's data and you should update that datatable object to make sure updated data is reflected everywhere, including the export.

To update the value of a single cell, you can call `table.cell().data()` as given in this documentation. https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data() which will update the datatable object, and you can call `draw()` method on that to update the html table.